# No route to host

Tags: directory

My laptop computer has Debian stable 7 installed and I downloaded the 64bit Tor.

I am unable to connect to Tor, the error message is below:

```
Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection.

Connecting to a relay directory failed (no route to host).

username@hostname:~$ cd tor
username@hostname:~/tor$ ./tor-browser
Launching Tor Browser for Linux in /home/username/tor/Browser...
1234567890123   addons.xpi-utils    ERROR   Unable to read anything useful from the database
Nov 13 03:21:22.183 [notice] Tor v0.2.5.10 (git-13318a95ddfbbf8d) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1i and Zlib 1.2.7.
Nov 13 03:21:22.183 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Nov 13 03:21:22.183 [notice] Read configuration file "/home/username/tor/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc-defaults".
Nov 13 03:21:22.183 [notice] Read configuration file "/home/username/tor/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc".
Nov 13 03:21:22.185 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9151
Nov 13 03:21:22.185 [notice] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
Nov 13 03:21:22.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /home/username/tor/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/geoip.
Nov 13 03:21:22.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /home/username/tor/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/geoip6.
Nov 13 03:21:22.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Nov 13 03:21:22.000 [notice] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
Nov 13 03:21:22.000 [notice] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
Nov 13 03:21:22.000 [notice] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
Nov 13 03:21:22.000 [notice] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
Nov 13 03:21:25.000 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
Nov 13 03:21:25.000 [notice] Renaming old configuration file to "/home/username/tor/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc.orig.1"
Nov 13 03:21:25.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
Nov 13 03:21:28.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (No route to host; NOROUTE; count 1; recommendation warn)
Nov 13 03:21:31.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (No route to host; NOROUTE; count 3; recommendation warn)
Nov 13 03:21:31.000 [warn] 2 connections have failed:
Nov 13 03:21:31.000 [warn]  2 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
```

I hope that to find a solution on this forum.

Some additional info

The hotel at which I am staying uses the default gateway 192.168.200.1 instead of the conventional 192.168.1.1.

I use a wired connection.

Comment: Are you able to connect to standard websites? Have you tried using a bridge?

Comment: @hexafraction Yes, I am able to connect to standard websites. Yes, I have tried using a bridge and I was still unable to connect to Tor.